# LDAP Configuration in Apache Superset

Tags: flask, ldap, apache-superset

Airbnb superset distribution used to provide few properties to configure LDAP authentication via Flask for Superset. While trying to implement the Apache Superset Distro, unable to find anything that maps to the following variables:

```
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD=sAMAccountName
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER=CN=Bind,OU=Admin,dc=our,dc=domain
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH=OU=Employees,dc=our,dc=domain
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER=ldap://our.domain
AUTH_LDAP=AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_LDAP_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED=True
AUTH_LDAP_APPEND_DOMAIN=False
AUTH_LDAP_FIRSTNAME_FIELD=givenName
AUTH_LDAP_LASTNAME_FIELD=sn
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS=False
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION=True
ENABLE_KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION=True
KERBEROS_KEYTAB=/etc/security/keytabs/superset.headless.keytab
KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL=superset-sdrdev@OUR.DOMAIN}
```

Master branch on *https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset* does not contain any documentation on configuring LDAP configs.

Anybody had any success with this ?

Comment: Did you take a look at this: https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#authentication-ldap

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it's working with me:

Configuration LDAP

```
AUTH_TYPE = 2
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = False
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = "uid"
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldap://ldap:389"
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "ou=users,dc=exampl,dc=org"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "cn=admin,dc=openpaas,dc=org"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "secret"
```